# How to recover BIOS supervisor password?

Tags: debian, bios, passwords

I have a machine with a Phoenix BIOS and am running Debian 9.

The BIOS has a supervisor and user roles. I can enter in as a user but the supervisor password is unknown. There are settings in the BIOS I want to change but only the supervisor is allowed to do this.

I see that there are ways to reset it but is there a way for me to somehow recover it and know what the password is?

I have tried using the backdoor passwords listed in various articles to gain supervisor permissions but none of them seem to work.

The machine still boots to the OS so I am not locked out.

Answer (score 2):

> I see that there are ways to reset it but is there a way for me to
> somehow recover it and know what the password is?

No.  Someone set the password, so try your existing User password.

Otherwise you need to reset it to something you do know.

@Kevin - you said you saw ways to reset it, so I assume you can. It depends upon the machine and I do not know the one above.

Comment: You might explain how to reset the password.

Comment: I suggested the Author post the method known to them. My own machines are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover it, but in most cases (not all motherboards allow this) you can clear the CMOS with a jumper in the motherboard or other ways.
Search the manual for your specific motherboard and check if it's possible to clear the CMOS in your model.